# Difference between 'race' and 'race over'

Tags: meaning

I would like to ask you, if you can help me with distinction of meaning between *race* and *race over*.

I assume that if someone races he competes with someone else, but race over (as in, *he raced over to his office*) means something like *hurrying somewhere*. Is this correct?

Comment: Please could you include your research?

Comment: There's no real difference between "raced over to", "strolled over to", "walked over to", and a dictionary will tell you what you want to know. Note that "ran over to Nicholas" is not the same as "ran over Nicholas", so the ***to*** is important as well.

Comment: _Race_, with or without _over_, can also mean _run as though competing in a race_.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Do you mean no difference grammatically? They certainly mean very different things.

Comment: As @Andrew suggests, the real issue here is the function of 'over' in 'come over [to]' (actually discussed before on ELU, 'go over [to] [see Charlotte]', 'walk over to', 'stroll over to', 'race/tear over to' .... It's merely a tautological padder, with semi-retrievable concepts 'over the intervening ground / fields / part of town / Channel  ...'.

Comment: race||over to x, is not just race. It is true that race can be any number of motion verbs. race over to x, walk over to x, run over to, but so can the preposition: under x, around x, etc. walk under x, sprint over x. In short, a verb + a prepositional phrase, implied or in fact.

Answer (score 0):

While "race over (to)" does convey specifically the meaning of moving to a place quickly, note that "race" can also be used in this context:

```
He raced home to share the good news.
```